Matplotlib and Numpy showing y-tick labels overlapping
Using Seaborn, Matplotlib, Seaborn, and pandas to make scatterplots. Am very new to Python. No errors but my y-axis tick labels are overlapping and bloating.
Other advice on this forum such as tilting or reformatting the labels has not helped.
startdate=data['FieldActivityStartDate']
plt.scatter(latitude,startdate,color='green')
plt.xlabel('Latitude')
plt.ylabel('Field Start Date')
plt.show()

Produces this? How can I separate the y-axis tick labels?


Would you be able to share sample data?

Have you tried by changing the fontsize? plt.yticks(fontsize=10), change the value with what you need. You can also set the rotation by expressing the degrees: plt.yticks(rotation=45)

what other advice do you mean? You could describe it in question (not in comments)

Are your dates currently strings? https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order

Does this answer your question? Difference in plotting with different matplotlib versions
